# Database sharding with replication - delay

Tags: sql-server, replication, sharding

We are thinking of sharding our database with replication. Our usecases include reads and writes to parts of shards. We have questions like

1. How long the delays would be in replication?
2. Will there be any data redundancy if one server goes down and comes back (because of delay in replication)?

Comment: Why not test all this out on a couple of test servers? I mean you are going to have to do that anyway.

Comment: Just wanted to hear insights from those who did this before we attempt. Thanks.